# Ember1.0 version, how to get the entire object from event click (analogous to event.context in version 0.9)?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, dom-events

I am new to emberjs and there seems to be very less documentation around. Initially I started using ember0.9 version and I had a collection of patient objects which can be displayed on the UI, when I click on the specific row, (using `event.context`) I was able to retrieve entire object but with ember1.0 (latest) version the context itself seems to be missing from the event object, although I was able to get the id and retrieve the full object from the server call (not recommended), I really want to know if there is a way to retrieve the entire object from the event.

```
     {{#each Em.App.patientsController}}
      <tr id="row">
        <td id="patient"><div {{action showPatient href=true}}>{{_id}}</div></td>
        <td id="account">{{name}}</td>
        <td id="location">{{name}}</td>
        
      </tr>
    {{/each}}
    //in ember0.9, whats the equivalent in ember1.0
    showPatient: function(event) {
    var patientObj = event.context;
    }
```

Comment: interesting...i started using 1.0 version directly so was unaware of this..but would like to know if this is still possible...

Answer (score 4):

You need to specify the action like this:

```
{{action showPatient this href=true}}
```

The second argument (`this` in my example) will become the `event.context`.